# Firebase client error: Custom token corresponds to a different audience

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm using the Firebase Python AdminSDK to generate a custom token which a Javascript client uses to sign in to Firebase.  When the JS client tries to authenticate with the custom token it gets the error "Custom token corresponds to a different audience".

The code given with the error:  'auth/custom-token-mismatch'.

Many Google'd answers regarding the "audience" mismatch reference Analytics.  But I'm doing a Web project, not iOS or Android, so I can't use Analytics to manage audiences.

The SO answers I've read are listed at the end, below.

I captured the custom token and plugged it in to https://jwt.io/ and both the values and the instanciation/expiration times (an hour apart) look good:

Decoded custom token on jwt.io:

```
{
  "claims": {},
  "uid": "<myuniqueID",
  "sub": "firebase-adminsdk-1knpr@firebase-<myproject>.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "iss": "firebase-adminsdk-1knpr@firebase-<myproject>.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "iat": 1540153710,
  "aud": "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
  "exp": 1540157310
}
```

Python server:

```
def getFirebaseInstance():  # For Firebase Python SDK
  try:
    currentDir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    cred = credentials.Certificate(currentDir_path + '/includeFirebaseServiceAccounts/firebase-<myprojectname>-firebase-adminsdk-1knpr-e1244dd261.json')  
    firebaseAdmin = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, { 'databaseURL': 'https://<myprojectname>.firebaseio.com', 'databaseAuthVariableOverride': {'uid':'<myuniqueServerID>'}})
    if firebaseAdmin:
      return(firebaseAdmin)
  except:
    raise


def firebaseClientToken(request):
  try:
    uid = "<myuniqueClientID>"  # case sensitive
    additional_claims = { }
    token = auth.create_custom_token(uid,additional_claims)
    return HttpResponse(token)
  except Exception as err:
    return HttpResponse("System error:" + str(err), status=406)
```

Javascript client:

```
(
function authClient2Firebase() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "firebaseClientToken/",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(response) { step2(response); },
    error: function(xhr) { alert("There was an error loading a security check.  Have you lost your internet connection?  Detail:" + xhr.responseText); }
  });

  function step2(customToken) {
    try {
      firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(customToken).catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
          alert("There was an error with the secure login. \n\nDetail: " + errorMessage + '\nCode: ' + errorCode);
      });
    }
    catch(err) {
      alert(err);
    }

    console.log("authClient2Firebase.js: Firebase login succeeded!");
  }
}

)();
```

My project under the Console "Settings" page does have a Web API key, but I don't see anywhere that it's used.

There's only one user, me, under the Console's "Settings"->"Users and Permissions" page.

There's only one service account listed on the Console "Settings"->"Service Accounts" page.  I tried deleting all secrets on that page, generating a new one, then generating and installing a new blue-button "secret" (bad name, actually it generates a whole json credential object).

These are the domains listed in Console "Authentication" -> "Sign-in Method":

```
localhost                      Default
<myproject>.firebaseapp.com    Default
127.0.0.1                      Custom
auth.firebase.com              Custom
```

The actual domain I'm using is localhost:8000, which can't be entered here.

SO answers consulted unsuccessfully:

> [The custom token corresponds to a different audience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52454860/the-custom-token-corresponds-to-a-different-audience)
>   (I'm not using a key, except what's stored in the ServiceAccount
>   credentials.)
>
> [Firebase token error, "The custom token corresponds to a different audience."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37478705/firebase-token-error-the-custom-token-corresponds-to-a-different-audience)
>
> [Firebase custom auth issue token different audience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39067121/firebase-custom-auth-issue-token-different-audience)[enter
>   link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39067121/firebase-custom-auth-issue-token-different-audience)  (Close, but I'm not using a Node server and
>   not sure what he means by server "must belong to the same project"
>   since the Python server isn't registered in any way except through the
>   ServiceAccount credentials which I downloaded.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Embarrassing but true, it turned out to be a simple oversight.  When the JS client initialized itself as a Firebase app, before authenticating, it was using old credentials from a test environment.

```js
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  apiKey: "<WebAPI from Firebase console, 'Project Settings'>",
  authDomain: "<myproject>.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://<myproject>.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "<myproject>",
  storageBucket: "<myproject>.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "<id from Console Project Settings>" // optional
};
    
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Comment: If you are using a different Firebase project for testing, don't forget to enable the authentication methods you are using in your test project too, through Firebase Console.